# How to check for palindrome excluding the non-alphanumeric characters?

Tags: java

Here's the code that I attempted

```
public String isPalindrome(String s) {


    String trimmed = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");


    String reversed = "";

    int len = trimmed.length();


    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        char[] allChars = trimmed.toCharArray();

        reversed += allChars[i];

    }


    if (trimmed.equalsIgnoreCase(reversed)) {
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }

}
```

Sample Input 1
A man, a plan, a canal: Panama

Sample Output 1
true

Explanation 1
The given string is palindrome when considering only alphanumeric characters.

Sample Input 2
race a car

Sample Output 2
false

Explanation 2
The given string is not a palindrome when considering alphanumeric characters.

Comment: `It's throwing index out of bounds exception. Is the logic okay?` - when code produces a `RuntimeException` it can't be ok

Comment: Your method is returning String "true" or "false". You could consider a boolean return type.

Comment: input - "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama" output - "true"            but input - "race a car" output - "false"

Comment: Have a look at the exception stack-trace, you'll find information which on which line it occurs and what was the invalid, index you were trying to access. And this information should be present in your question.

Comment: Creating array `char[]` via `trimmed.toCharArray();` at each iteration step is redundant and costful.

Comment: How to ignore these " .,? " in string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `len` comes from the length of the String `s`. But you use the value on the array coming from `trimmed`.

So if you want to remove the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` you should change your `len` declaration to:

`int len = trimmed.length();`

Answer (score 0):

You can return `boolean` instead of `String`:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    String trimmed = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "").toLowerCase();

    int from = 0, to = trimmed.length() - 1;
    while (from < to) {
        if (trimmed.charAt(from) != trimmed.charAt(to)) {
            return false;
        }
        from++;
        to--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder to reverse a String:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "a#b!b^a";
    String clean = input.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(clean).reverse().toString();
    boolean isPalindrome = reverse.equals(clean);
    System.out.println(isPalindrome);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in linear time as the loops are driven by the presence of non-alphabetic/digit characters.  Also, no trimming or reversal of the string is required.

```
String[] test =  {"A man,  a plan, a canal: Panama",
         "race a car","foobar", "ABC2CEc2cba"};

for (String s : test) {
     System.out.printf("%5b -> %s%n", isPalindrome(s), s);
}
```

prints

```
 true ->    A man,  a plan, a canal: Panama 
false -> race a car
false -> foobar
 true -> ABC2CEc2cba
```

The outer while loop drives then entire process until the indices cross or are equal.  The inner loops simply skip over `non-alphabetic/digit` characters.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    int k = s.length() - 1;
    int i = 0;
    char c1 = '#';
    char c2 = '#';
    while (i <= k) {
        while (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c1 = s.charAt(i++)));
        while (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c2 = s.charAt(k--)));
        if (Character.toLowerCase(c1) != Character.toLowerCase(c2)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```